# How to truly determine empty string?

Tags: php, string

I'm trying to prevent users from entering an empty user name.
To determine spaces i use this code:

```
if (strlen($nickname) > 0 && strlen(trim($nickname)) == 0)
{
die("Your username is empty");
}
```

it works but when the user presses Alt+0160 and space together, above condition does not hold, so how can I determine if the user name consists of only spaces and alt+0160's or any other characters that result in an empty char?

Comment: I recommend you whitelist rather than blacklist. There's probably hundreds of Unicode whitespace characters that you can't handle.

Comment: You don't need the first part of the if statement if you have the second.

Comment: Your logic won't match anything. If $nickname is > 0, how could it also be == 0?

Comment: @Dave Nickname consist of only whitespace characters...

Comment: Little offtopic, you made me win the "Peer pressure" badge, as I deleted my fast answer. I am sorry I just focused on the title description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
$nickname = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9]/","",$str); //only things from the alfabet + numbers
if( strlen( $nickname ) < 1){
  // error
}
```

You filter out the things you dont want (in this case, only allow what you want), and check the length of the string afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply filter the string first

```
$string = filter_var($string,FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING , FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW | FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH );
```

Comment: can I ask why FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW | FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW?

Comment: `FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW` Strips characters that has a numerical value <32. while `FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH`  Strips characters that has a numerical value >127.

Comment: Yes, but why are you bitwise ORing `FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW` against itself? In other words, we think you must've made a typo because that makes no sense.

Comment: Thanks! But I still can't get this to work. should new $string return an empty string, if the chars are not between 32 and 127 ?